# Classes coupled with each other by generics

Tags: c#, generics, types, nested-generics

I'm currently learning C# and I'm coming from Java. In Java, I can do something like this:

```
public interface BasePresenterView<T extends BaseActivityPresenter> {}
public interface BaseActivityPresenter<T extends BasePresenterView> {}
```

and in C# I'm having a hard time achieving the same thing.

Comment: You have circullar dependency: BasePresenterView is generic with parameter BaseActivityPresenter  and BaseActivityPresenter is generic with parameter BasePresenterView.  I don't think it's really possible

Comment: Jeez, first few hours with the language and I'm already banging my head against the wall. Not good :/

Comment: In .Net it is convention to make all interfaces with a prefixed capital `I`  And mostly reserve the word `Base` for abstract classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I resolved it :)

```
public interface BaseActivityPresenter<T, K> 
        where T : BasePresenterView<T, K>
        where K : BaseActivityPresenter<T, K> {}

public interface BasePresenterView<T, K> 
        where T : BasePresenterView<T, K>
        where K : BaseActivityPresenter<T, K> {}
```

That seems to be working... for now. I don't know if this is a proper approach.

Comment: while it doesn't much matter...  I'd suggest you do `<TView, TPresenter>` versus `<T,K>`

Comment: @MatthewWhited yeah, that's a wise suggestion, I'll do that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is called generic constrained in .NET.

Your example in C# will look like this.

```
public interface BasePresenterView<T> where T: 'Interface or Type'{}
public interface BaseActivityPresenter<T> where T: 'Interface or Type' {}
```

**More info**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

EDIT: As already mentioned circular dependencies are not possible in C#, so you can not constraint them in the same way as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [generic type constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), which restrict compile-time types using inheritance.

```
public interface BasePresenterView<T> where T : IBaseView
```

Because inheritance cannot be circular, you cannot have the circular dependancy as in the question.

However, if they declare the same methods or properties, they could inherit the same interface:

```
public interface BasePresenterView     : IBaseView
public interface BaseActivityPresenter : IBaseView
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this if you are using abstract base classes...

```
public abstract class MyBasePresenter 
{
}
public abstract class MyBasePresenter<TView> : MyBasePresenter
    where TView : MyBaseView
{
}

public abstract class MyBaseView
{
}
public abstract class MyBaseView<TPresenter> : MyBaseView
    where TPresenter : MyBasePresenter
{
}

public class MyView : MyBaseView<MyPresenter>
{
}
public class MyPresenter : MyBasePresenter<MyView>
{
}
```

... do this if you want interfaces ...

```
public interface IMyPresenter 
{
}
public interface IMyPresenter<TView> : IMyPresenter
    where TView : IMyView
{
}

public interface IMyView
{
}
public interface IMyView<TPresenter> : IMyView
    where TPresenter : IMyPresenter
{
}

public class MyView : IMyView<MyPresenter>
{
}    
public class MyPresenter : IMyPresenter<MyView>
{
}
```

... of you really want to go crazy you can even nest the generics ...

```
public class MyView : IMyView<IMyPresenter<IMyView>>
{
}
```